# createinstallmedia: cannot execute binary file

Tags: macos, install, bootable-disk

I have downloaded the Sierra Installer from the App Store and I would like to make a bootable thumbdrive out of it.

I tried using the `createinstallmedia` binary that the installer ships with but got the following error:

```
/Applications/Install macOS Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia: cannot execute binary file
```

What happened? How do I go about fixing it?

Comment: Can you  correct your post so we can see the whole command that you have given? Further you need root privileges - try it with sudo.

Comment: @dante12 I got the error by just running it i.e. `sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redownloaded the installer. And everything works fine.

p.s. I'm in China at the moment. Look like package loss is a real problem here.